# Border-radius hidden by inner div

Tags: html, css

I have a div as a content box and have another div inside that for the title. The outer div has border-radius set but the inner div hides it.

**HTML:**

```
<div id='box'>
    <div id='boxTitle'>
        This is the title
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#box {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #bbb;
}
#boxTitle {
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AAUbA/

How do I fix it so I can see the rounded corners at the top of the outer?

Comment: You can put border-top-left and border-top-right to the `#boxTitle`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `overflow: hidden` on your `#box` element:

```
#box {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #bbb;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

See the updated Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/AAUbA/2/

As an aside: it's worth considering adding in vendor-prefixes to ensure better cross-browser compatibility.

[This](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/) is a good write-up on how to use the property.
You can use [this tool](http://border-radius.com/) to auto-generate the CSS you need.

Comment: Perfect! And I appreciate the link for x-browser support :)

Comment: +1 as a side-note: Nowadays [you could dropped the vendor-prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius#Browser_compatibility) for the `border-radius` property.

Comment: Glad to have been of help!  Feel free to mark the correct answer when you're done (it helps future visitors to the site find the answer), and feel free to open up further questions if you need further help.

Comment: Will do in 7 mins when it lets me :)

Comment: @HashemQolami is absolutely correct that you don't necessarily need to use vendor prefixes by the way.  It all depends on who you're targeting.  You can see up-to-date compatibility charts [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius) (that site is a very useful reference point). You'll sill need to use `-webkit` for previous iOS and Andriod devices.

Answer (score 5):

Give `#boxTitle` the same radius on both the top corners as the box. As already suggested you can also set the overflow to hidden with `overflow:hidden;`. Both working but if you want to add something outside of `#box` it won't be displayed, with this code it will be displayed:

HTML:

```
<div id='box'>
    <div id='boxTitle'>
        This is the title
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#box {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #bbb;
}

#boxTitle {
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgD2/)

Comment: I thought about this but thought it would be a bit messy

Comment: @matt1985 why would be "a bit messy"?

Comment: It won't be messy, as I wrote: using `overflow:hidden;` is messier, cause if you want something on the outside of the box, it won't be displayed. Therefor I prefer not to use `overflow:hidden;` cause it ain't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

add overflow: hidden on your #box element.